# Hide iTerm ScrollBar

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

How can I hide the scrollbar of my iterm console?

Answer (score 50):

In iTerm's prefs menu/dialog:

`iTerm > Preferences > Appearance > Window > "Hide scrollbar and resize control"`

[image: iTerm 2 Preference Pane]

Comment: This is an old question and answer, but they did not implement this in iTerm2.

Comment: They actually have implemented it. I've added a screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: I must be using an old version at home; I see it at work but not there.  I'll upgrade.  Thanks for the screenshot!

Comment: In iTerm2 v3.x, this setting is in the same area of Preferences but is now called simply `Hide scrollbars`.